# Logging errors in WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("HOLY MICE!");
    }
}
```

See that exception? I want to log that. I also want to log exceptions that I don't expect. Pretty simple, right?

So, I did this:

[image: wcf tracing config]

Amazingly, I don't see anything about "HOLY MICE!" in that log file that is generated. I wonder why that is?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your trace level to trace errors.  It looks like you have "Trace Level: Warning"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the trace level to Error. <strike>Warning won't log exceptions and the trace level doesn't roll up (for example, setting to Warning would not include Error and Critical)</strike> Update: I'm completely wrong, it does roll up

[MSDN Link of each trace level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: Just making sure, but you are calling that method from a client right? Does it show up as an exception on the client side?

Comment: Calling from Silverlight client. Shows up as the infamous "Not Found". But I don't care about that. I'm more concerned about getting the logging working server side.